# How is Laplace operator defined on a pde solution $u(x,y,t)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

What is the definition of $\Delta u(x,y,t)$, where $\Delta$ stands for Laplace operator?

$x,y$: spatial variables

$t$: time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually it is just $$\Delta u(x,y,t) = u_{xx}(x,y,t) + u_{yy}(x,y,t).$$
So the time variable is ignored.